# Run Spring web service when running JUnit test

Tags: eclipse, spring, google-app-engine, junit

I have a application that is a Spring-based web service using AppEngine.

To do test with the Service accessing the resources though its URL,

- I first run the web application
- Then run the JUnit test

It works, however is it possible to trigger the web application to run and shutdown when I run the JUnit test and when it finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you probably shouldn't be unit testing against a live webservice (that's really integration testing), I see no reson why you couldn't start the web app, eg using Jetty programmatically in a `@Before` method.

```
Server jettyServer = new Server();
SocketConnector conn = new SocketConnector();
conn.setPort( 8080 );
jettyServer.setConnectors( new Connector[]{ conn } );
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setContextPath( "/yourcontext" );
context.setWar( "src/main/webapp" );
jettyServer.setHandler( context );
jettyServer.start();
```

Cheers,

Comment: This will work with AppEngine? AppEngine use a different Jetty right?

Comment: My answers assumes that you would be running the webservice locally.